# want to see logcat on real phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

My application works very fine on emulator without any `logcat` error, but it abruptly being `crashed` on real android device. So I want to see logcat on real android tablet. And i had alos lost my `usb connector` so please tell me something so I can view `logcat` on android tablet.Please suggest me some ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

install logcat app in your mobile [click here for app in android market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd)

Answer (score 3):

Go [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result) and install this application on  your device. It will work very nice and you can see your logcat error on your phone without connecting to your pc!