# Published android app crashing

Tags: android

In the emulator, and in the device i used to test the app, it ran smoothly. Today I published it to the market, and after i try to click a button to move to another page, It crashes.

I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but did not help. I tried the emulator again to see if i may have done something to the app, but the emulator still works fine.

Does anyone know what problem this could be? If i need to post more information, just let me know. Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:
Type of crash: It says "Unfortunately, [app name] has stopped."

EDIT 2: Logcat

```
11-11 23:30:16.487: I/InputReader(2118): dispatchTouch::touch event's action is 1 (deviceType=0) [pCnt=1, pending(waiting finished signal)=0]
11-11 23:30:16.487: I/InputDispatcher(2118): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'xxxx'
11-11 23:30:16.487: I/InputDispatcher(2118): Delivering touch to current input target: action: 1, channel 'xxxx'
11-11 23:30:16.492: I/AudioService(2118): playSoundEffect() type:0 volume:-1
11-11 23:30:16.492: I/AudioPolicyManagerBase(2088): getSituationVolume: isBTConnected:0 isHeadConnected:0
11-11 23:30:16.492: I/AudioPolicyManager(2088): getParamFromPolicy  deviceInt = 0, situationInt = 1, situationVolume = 0.300000
11-11 23:30:16.497: I/AudioPolicyManager(2088): startOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 2857
11-11 23:30:16.497: I/AudioFlinger(2088): start output streamType (0, 1) for 1
11-11 23:30:16.497: V/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::createVolume()
11-11 23:30:16.497: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088): UserDep::getRouteInfo(output: audioengine=0, devices=00000002h
11-11 23:30:16.497: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       incall: onoff=0, devices=00000000h
11-11 23:30:16.497: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       capture: onoff=0, devices=00000000h, audioSource=0
11-11 23:30:16.497: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       playback: audio_onoff=0, line_onoff=0)
11-11 23:30:16.497: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088): ALL Off
11-11 23:30:16.497: V/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::setVolume()
11-11 23:30:16.497: D/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::setVolume() FM Playback: Ready
11-11 23:30:16.497: D/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::setVolume() VoiceCall: Ready
11-11 23:30:16.507: D/CLIPBOARD(2118): Hide Clipboard dialog inside hideSoftInput() !
11-11 23:30:16.507: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 4
11-11 23:30:16.507: D/lights(2118): set_light_notifications -1 0xff00ff00
11-11 23:30:16.507: D/lights(2118): handle_speaker_battery_locked: 0xffff0000, 0xff00ff00
11-11 23:30:16.507: D/lights(2118): set_led_state 0xFFFF0000, onMS=0, offMS=0
11-11 23:30:16.507: E/lights(2118): ***** Charging : RED Solid *****
11-11 23:30:16.507: E/lights(2118): led_type= 1,interval= 0
11-11 23:30:16.507: E/lights(2118): reverse= 0,blink_cnt= 0
11-11 23:30:16.507: E/lights(2118): RilD >> InvokeOemRequestHookRaw ret= 0
11-11 23:30:16.507: V/InputManagerService(2118): Client requesting input be hidden
11-11 23:30:16.507: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #4 #ff00ff00
11-11 23:30:16.527: D/PowerManagerService(2118): mIsSipVisible : false
11-11 23:30:16.752: D/dalvikvm(2118): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6236K, 40% free 20627K/34119K, paused 4ms+6ms
11-11 23:30:16.762: I/SurfaceFlinger(1754): id=1495 Removed idx=1 Map Size=4
11-11 23:30:16.762: I/SurfaceFlinger(1754): id=1495 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=4
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3098)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3620)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14292)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3093)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    ... 11 more
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1099)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:194)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at com.phil.avatarview.AvatarViewActivity.fetch(AvatarViewActivity.java:82)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at com.phil.avatarview.AvatarViewActivity.ImageOperations(AvatarViewActivity.java:68)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    at com.phil.avatarview.AvatarViewActivity.firstbutton(AvatarViewActivity.java:59)
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075):    ... 14 more
11-11 23:30:16.827: E/android.os.Debug(2118): !@Dumpstate > dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
11-11 23:30:16.832: I/ALSAModule(2088): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device hifi
11-11 23:30:16.842: I/dumpstate(14132): Check if stand-alone
11-11 23:30:16.847: I/dumpstate(14132): begin
11-11 23:30:16.997: I/AudioPolicyManager(2088): stopOutput() output 1, stream 1, session 2857
11-11 23:30:17.022: I/AudioFlinger(2088): stop output streamType (0, 1) for 1
11-11 23:30:17.072: D/BatteryService(2118): update start
11-11 23:30:17.077: D/BatteryService(2118): level:18 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 3749 temperature: 320 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17302822 invalid charger:0
11-11 23:30:17.327: W/ActivityManager(2118): Activity pause timeout for r
11-11 23:30:17.522: V/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::createVolume()
11-11 23:30:17.522: D/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): Dir0      : AP Playback Music SP (0001h)

11-11 23:30:17.522: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088): UserDep::getRouteInfo(output: audioengine=0, devices=00000002h
11-11 23:30:17.522: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       incall: onoff=0, devices=00000000h
11-11 23:30:17.522: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       capture: onoff=0, devices=00000000h, audioSource=0
11-11 23:30:17.522: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       playback: audio_onoff=1, line_onoff=0)
11-11 23:30:17.847: W/PowerManagerService(2118): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
11-11 23:30:18.532: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(2438): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
11-11 23:30:20.087: I/ALSAModule(2088): Terminated ALSA PLAYBACK device hifi
11-11 23:30:20.507: V/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::createVolume()
11-11 23:30:20.507: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088): UserDep::getRouteInfo(output: audioengine=0, devices=00000002h
11-11 23:30:20.507: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       incall: onoff=0, devices=00000000h
11-11 23:30:20.507: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       capture: onoff=0, devices=00000000h, audioSource=0
11-11 23:30:20.507: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088):                       playback: audio_onoff=0, line_onoff=0)
11-11 23:30:20.507: V/yamaha::media::UserDep(2088): ALL Off
11-11 23:30:20.507: V/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::setVolume()
11-11 23:30:20.507: D/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::setVolume() FM Playback: Ready
11-11 23:30:20.507: D/yamaha::media::VolumeCtrl(2088): VolumeCtrl::setVolume() VoiceCall: Ready
11-11 23:30:20.557: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(2438): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
11-11 23:30:22.587: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(2438): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
11-11 23:30:23.337: D/VoldCmdListener(1746): asec list
11-11 23:30:23.342: D/VoldCmdListener(1746): CommandListener::AsecCmd::runCommand -> -- 
11-11 23:30:24.612: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(2438): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
11-11 23:30:26.397: D/PowerManagerService(2118): mIsLockZone =  false
11-11 23:30:36.507: E/AlarmManagerService(2118): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=1, 1352696400.000000000
11-11 23:30:39.347: W/PowerManagerService(2118): Timer 0x3->0x1|0x0
11-11 23:30:39.347: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.347: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 30
11-11 23:30:39.347: I/PowerManagerService(2118): Ulight 3->1|0
11-11 23:30:39.347: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff1e1e1e
11-11 23:30:39.367: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.367: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 29
11-11 23:30:39.367: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff1d1d1d
11-11 23:30:39.382: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.382: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 28
11-11 23:30:39.382: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff1c1c1c
11-11 23:30:39.397: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.397: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 27
11-11 23:30:39.397: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff1b1b1b
11-11 23:30:39.412: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.412: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 26
11-11 23:30:39.412: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff1a1a1a
11-11 23:30:39.432: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.432: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 25
11-11 23:30:39.432: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff191919
11-11 23:30:39.447: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.447: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 24
11-11 23:30:39.447: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff181818
11-11 23:30:39.462: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.462: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 23
11-11 23:30:39.462: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff171717
11-11 23:30:39.477: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.477: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 22
11-11 23:30:39.477: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff161616
11-11 23:30:39.492: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.492: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 21
11-11 23:30:39.492: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff151515
11-11 23:30:39.512: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:39.512: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 20
11-11 23:30:39.512: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff141414
11-11 23:30:39.512: I/PowerManagerService(2118): Light Animator Finished curIntValue=20
11-11 23:30:40.467: I/dumpstate(14132): done
11-11 23:30:40.562: D/BatteryService(2118): update start
11-11 23:30:40.562: D/PowerManagerService(2118): acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 1000000  uid : 1000  pid : 2118  tag : ActivityManager
11-11 23:30:40.567: I/power(2118): *** acquire_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1  freq : 1000000 
11-11 23:30:40.572: W/ActivityManager(2118): mDVFSLock.acquire()
11-11 23:30:40.582: D/BatteryService(2118): level:18 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 3751 temperature: 320 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17302822 invalid charger:0
11-11 23:30:40.587: D/WimaxStateTracker(2118): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: WIMAX[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: true, isAvailable: false
11-11 23:30:40.587: W/WifiStateTracker(2118): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: WIFI[], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true
11-11 23:30:40.587: E/WifiP2pStateTracker(2118): getNetworkInfo : NetworkInfo: type: wifi_p2p[], state: UNKNOWN/IDLE, reason: (unspecified), extra: (none), roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false
11-11 23:30:40.612: D/BatteryService(2118): update start
11-11 23:30:40.617: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
11-11 23:30:40.617: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - level:18
11-11 23:30:40.617: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - plugged:2
11-11 23:30:40.617: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
11-11 23:30:40.622: V/WindowOrientationListener(2118): nearestRotation : 0   Angle: 10   tilt: 49
11-11 23:30:40.622: W/ActivityManager(2118): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
11-11 23:30:40.627: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2118): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
11-11 23:30:40.627: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2118): handleBatteryUpdate
11-11 23:30:40.627: D/UiModeManager(2118): mLastBroadcastState = 0mCarModeEnabled = falseisDeskDockState(mDockState) = false
11-11 23:30:40.627: V/UiModeManager(2118): updateLocked: null action, mDockState=0, firing homeIntent: null
11-11 23:30:40.627: D/UiModeManager(2118): updateConfigurationLocked: mDockState=0; mCarMode=false; mNightMode=0; uiMode=17
11-11 23:30:40.632: I/SurfaceFlinger(1754): id=1496(217) createSurface 0x47704 (1x1),1 flag=0
11-11 23:30:40.637: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2118): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
11-11 23:30:40.637: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2118): handleBatteryUpdate
11-11 23:30:40.637: D/UiModeManager(2118): mLastBroadcastState = 0mCarModeEnabled = falseisDeskDockState(mDockState) = false
11-11 23:30:40.637: V/UiModeManager(2118): updateLocked: null action, mDockState=0, firing homeIntent: null
11-11 23:30:40.637: D/UiModeManager(2118): updateConfigurationLocked: mDockState=0; mCarMode=false; mNightMode=0; uiMode=17
11-11 23:30:40.642: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
11-11 23:30:40.642: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - level:18
11-11 23:30:40.642: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - plugged:2
11-11 23:30:40.642: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
11-11 23:30:40.707: D/Finsky(8292): [1] DetailsDataBasedFragment.rebindViews: Page [class=DetailsFragment] loaded in [585430 ms] (partial? false)
11-11 23:30:40.727: I/SurfaceFlinger(1754): id=1497(26) createSurface 0x44624 (480x800),1 flag=400
11-11 23:30:40.767: D/dalvikvm(8292): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1270K, 23% free 12763K/16519K, paused 2ms+7ms
11-11 23:30:40.852: W/Finsky(8292): [1] HistogramView.bind: No histogram data received from server
11-11 23:30:40.862: D/Finsky(8292): [1] DetailsDataBasedFragment.rebindViews: Page [class=DetailsFragment] loaded in [585585 ms] (partial? true)
11-11 23:30:40.977: D/dalvikvm(2542): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 7% free 9432K/10055K, paused 1ms+2ms
11-11 23:30:41.422: I/power(2118): *** release_dvfs_lock : lockType : 1 
11-11 23:30:41.422: D/PowerManagerService(2118): releaseDVFSLockLocked : all DVFS_MIN_LIMIT are released 
11-11 23:30:41.422: W/ActivityManager(2118): mDVFSLock.release()
11-11 23:30:46.347: W/PowerManagerService(2118): Timer 0x1->0x0|0x0
11-11 23:30:46.347: D/PowerManagerService(2118): Screen__Off : Timeout
11-11 23:30:46.347: I/PowerManagerService(2118): Ulight 1->0|0
11-11 23:30:46.352: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.352: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 18
11-11 23:30:46.352: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff121212
11-11 23:30:46.367: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.367: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 17
11-11 23:30:46.367: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff111111
11-11 23:30:46.382: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.382: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 16
11-11 23:30:46.382: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff101010
11-11 23:30:46.402: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.402: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 15
11-11 23:30:46.402: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff0f0f0f
11-11 23:30:46.417: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.417: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 14
11-11 23:30:46.417: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff0e0e0e
11-11 23:30:46.432: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.432: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 13
11-11 23:30:46.432: D/PowerManagerService(2118): Tilt onSensorChanged : return, isScreenTurningOffLocked : true
11-11 23:30:46.432: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff0d0d0d
11-11 23:30:46.447: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.447: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 12
11-11 23:30:46.447: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff0c0c0c
11-11 23:30:46.462: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.462: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 11
11-11 23:30:46.462: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff0b0b0b
11-11 23:30:46.482: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.482: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 10
11-11 23:30:46.482: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff0a0a0a
11-11 23:30:46.497: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.497: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 8
11-11 23:30:46.497: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff080808
11-11 23:30:46.512: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.512: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 7
11-11 23:30:46.512: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff070707
11-11 23:30:46.527: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.527: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 6
11-11 23:30:46.527: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff060606
11-11 23:30:46.547: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.547: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 5
11-11 23:30:46.547: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff050505
11-11 23:30:46.562: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.562: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 4
11-11 23:30:46.562: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff040404
11-11 23:30:46.577: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.577: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 3
11-11 23:30:46.577: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff030303
11-11 23:30:46.592: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.592: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 2
11-11 23:30:46.592: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff020202
11-11 23:30:46.612: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.612: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 1
11-11 23:30:46.612: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff010101
11-11 23:30:46.627: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 0
11-11 23:30:46.627: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/backlight/panel/brightness, value 0
11-11 23:30:46.627: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #0 #ff000000
11-11 23:30:46.632: I/power(2118): *** set_screen_state 0
11-11 23:30:46.632: D/SensorManager(2118): unregisterListener:: disable all sensors for this listener,  name = CM3663 Light Sensor listener = com.android.server.PowerManagerService$15@41714560
11-11 23:30:46.632: D/PowerManagerService(2118): Tilt onSensorChanged : return, isScreenTurningOffLocked : true
11-11 23:30:46.632: I/PowerManagerService(2118): Light Animator Finished curIntValue=0
11-11 23:30:46.632: D/PowerManagerService(2118): enableLightSensorLocked enable=false mAutoBrightessEnabled=true
11-11 23:30:46.637: I/SensorManager(2118): Set min delay = 200000
11-11 23:30:46.637: I/SensorManager(2118): Before sending... delay = 200000
11-11 23:30:46.637: D/Sensors(2118): Remain listener = android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418a4620
11-11 23:30:46.637: I/Sensors(2118): sendDelay --- 200000000
11-11 23:30:46.637: D/SensorManager(2118): JNI - sendDelay
11-11 23:30:46.642: D/SensorManager(2118): unregisterListener:: disable all sensors for this listener,  name = K3DH Acceleration Sensor listener = com.android.server.PowerManagerService$16@4173e160
11-11 23:30:46.642: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 2
11-11 23:30:46.642: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/devices/virtual/sec/sec_touchkey/brightness, value 2
11-11 23:30:46.642: D/LightsService(2118): setLight_native: 1
11-11 23:30:46.642: E/lights(2118): write_int: path /sys/class/leds/keyboard-backlight/brightness, value 0
11-11 23:30:46.642: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #2 #0
11-11 23:30:46.642: V/LightsService(2118): setLight #1 #0
11-11 23:30:46.642: W/PowerManagerService(2118): CurLockF mPS:0 mUS=0
11-11 23:30:46.642: W/PowerManagerService(2118): mPokeLocks.size=0:
11-11 23:30:46.642: D/PowerManagerService(2118): sendNotificationLocked on=false
11-11 23:30:46.657: D/SurfaceFlinger(1754): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0xfa68
11-11 23:30:46.667: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2118): onScreenTurnedOff(3)
11-11 23:30:46.667: D/PowerManagerService(2118): mNotificationTask : off
11-11 23:30:46.672: E/AlarmManagerService(2118): android_server_AlarmManagerService_set to type=2, 318374.438000000
11-11 23:30:46.672: D/KeyguardViewMediator(2118): setting alarm to turn off keyguard, seq = 253
11-11 23:30:46.677: D/Sensors(2118): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
11-11 23:30:46.677: I/Sensors(2118): sendDelay --- 200000000
11-11 23:30:46.677: D/SensorManager(2118): JNI - sendDelay
11-11 23:30:46.677: I/SensorManager(2118): Set normal delay = true
11-11 23:30:46.677: D/SensorManager(2118): unregisterListener:: disable all sensors for this listener,  name = K3DH Acceleration Sensor listener = android.view.WindowOrientationListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@418a4620
11-11 23:30:46.772: I/AudioHardwareYamaha(2088): AudioHardware::setParameters(keyValuePairs="screen_state=off")
11-11 23:30:46.872: W/AudioPolicyManager(2088): FM radio recording off
11-11 23:30:46.877: W/AudioPolicyManager(2088): FM radio recording off
11-11 23:30:46.877: W/AudioPolicyManager(2088): FM radio recording off
11-11 23:30:46.887: D/VolumePanel(2118): onVolumeChanged(streamType: 3, flags: 64)
11-11 23:30:46.887: D/AudioService(2118): getStreamVolume(3)
11-11 23:30:46.887: D/AudioService(2118): getStreamVolume(3)
11-11 23:30:46.922: W/Settings(2399): Setting lock_pattern_autolock has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
11-11 23:30:46.952: D/weatherclock(22802): [MSC_Accu]>>> WS:55 [0:0] action : android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
11-11 23:30:46.952: D/weatherclock(22802): [MSC_Accu]>>> WWP:2326 [0:0] mHandler is null!!
11-11 23:30:46.952: D/weatherclock(22802): [MSC_Accu]>>> WWP:373 [0:0] refreshhandler is null!!
11-11 23:30:47.232: D/BatteryService(2118): update start
11-11 23:30:47.237: D/BatteryService(2118): level:18 scale:100 status:2 health:2 present:true voltage: 3754 temperature: 320 technology: Li-ion AC powered:false USB powered:true icon:17302822 invalid charger:0
11-11 23:30:47.252: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2118): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
11-11 23:30:47.252: D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor(2118): handleBatteryUpdate
11-11 23:30:47.252: D/UiModeManager(2118): mLastBroadcastState = 0mCarModeEnabled = falseisDeskDockState(mDockState) = false
11-11 23:30:47.252: V/UiModeManager(2118): updateLocked: null action, mDockState=0, firing homeIntent: null
11-11 23:30:47.252: D/UiModeManager(2118): updateConfigurationLocked: mDockState=0; mCarMode=false; mNightMode=0; uiMode=17
11-11 23:30:47.257: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED
11-11 23:30:47.257: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - level:18
11-11 23:30:47.257: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - plugged:2
11-11 23:30:47.257: D/STATUSBAR-BatteryController(2344): onReceive() - BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING:
11-11 23:30:48.932: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(2438): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
11-11 23:30:50.956: W/InputConnectionWrapper.ICC(2438): Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback
11-11 23:30:51.436: W/ActivityManager(2118): Activity destroy timeout for r
```

Comment: post the error log which you are getting when you check your app in the mobile

Comment: Without seeing logcat error we can not do anything for you.

Comment: That is a sucky situation. Run your app while connected to your computer to see the LogCat.

Comment: Is the error log in the phone? When i run the app from just testing on eclipse on an emulator, and on the same phone from eclipse it works perfectly fine. Its only when I downloaded it from the market that it did not work.

Comment: @JeremyRowler attach your device with computer and see logcat error.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12363753/1265724) link may help you to post your error message

Comment: @Ramkiran he does need to know that if he does this it cannot be from JellyBean as its an extra security measure that was added on 4.1

Comment: ok i will install it and then post the logcat

Comment: @JeremyRowler don't install the app. It'd be easier to just connect your phone to your computer, select your phone from the DDMS and see the LogCat info from there -_-

Comment: @Andy, I just tell him the way to find his error. that's it.

Comment: @Ramkiran haha I know. But it was just easier to do it on the computer. No hard feelings!

Comment: ok i found it on the computer. I think the problem is "Timed out waiting on IInputContextCallback". Does anyone know anything about that?

Comment: Can you just post all of it please :)

Comment: Im trying to, but its really long and it does not want to let me post it all. When im trying to put it as code, its not really working. Any other way to post the logcat?

Comment: Ok, i got it up there, Good luck reading through it, It wasnt easy for me to do it. But then again im not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

this eror comes With HoneyComb(3.0 or Later). you can not perform a networking operation on its main thread as documentation says. to getting ride of this you  must use **handler** or **asynctask**. AFAIK There is no another way to do it.

you can See this for More Details [WHY ICS Crashes your App](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: I dont know how you were able to pick that out, but i thank you very much. It looks like I've got another couple weeks of coding to fix my broken app... Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 2):

This line in your LogCat:

```
11-11 23:30:16.797: E/AndroidRuntime(14075): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Is where your error lies. NetworkOnMainThread, meaning that you call a network request on the only thread for the app, if the network hangs, your app will stop responding to the OS, and crash. Try using async tasks, or use threads.

```
new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        //do your networking here    
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I dont know whos to accept. You guys are all providing really good answers. I will stick with Bhavesh although, because he provided the answer first. Thanks Matt for your help :)

Comment: I need 15 rep to upvote... Im not there yet... When i get it ill come back and upvote:)